# Find the smallest natural number that is divisible by 2 and by 3 and which is...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest natural number that is divisible by 2 and by 3, and which is
simultaneously the fourth power of an integer, and the sixth power of an integer

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you. (Also, I removed irrelevant tags.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

$2^{12}* 3^{12}$

$=2176782336$